# fixing pydantic dependency while working on RAG from pinecone (OpenAIEmbeddings)

Tags: pydantic, langchain, pinecone

How do I get around this error found for importing OpenAIEmbeddings in this [pinecone notebook link](https://github.com/pinecone-io/examples/blob/master/learn/generation/langchain/handbook/05-langchain-retrieval-augmentation.ipynb).

The error centers around this import: `from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings`

I first ran into this issue:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
langchain 0.0.162 requires pydantic<2,>=1, which is not installed.
apache-beam 2.49.0 requires protobuf<4.24.0,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.
pydantic-core 2.4.0 requires typing-extensions!=4.7.0,>=4.6.0, but you have typing-extensions 4.5.0 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.12.0 requires torch==1.12.0, but you have torch 1.12.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed typing-inspect-0.8.0 typing_extensions-4.5.0
```

Another recommendaiton found is to try this install: `pip install typing-inspect-0.8.0 typing_extensions-4.5.0`, but ran into the same problem.